# read from file after calling lseek64 - Linux

Tags: c, linux, file

I'm trying to read a large file (> 2.0 GB).
The seeking is done by lseek64, then I tried to read using read(fileHandle, buffer, bufferLength)\ pread64(fileHandle, buffer, bufferLength, offset) - but both return with -1.

What could it be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: More context please. How big is the file? Where are you seeking to? Does it work if you seek to small offsets?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code fragment ? It's pretty hard to debug this otherwise...

Comment: The file's size is 2.39 GB, but it happens also with other files with similiar sizes. errno's value is EIO.

Comment: It's quite hard to cut just the relevant code (This is a part of a library that does much more...) but an important part: I run it on Redhat that runs on a virtual machine, and the file is actually on the host (not on the RedHat VM itself).
Thank you all!

Comment: at least put a perror() statement after the read which will give a more precise explanation for why it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

before you include the syscall headers? Otherwise, show some code.

Answer (score -1):

```
ssize_t count = read(fileHandle, buffer, bufferLength);
if ( count == -1 )
{
 fprintf(stderr, "can't read file: %m\n");
 exit(1);
}
```